# Why the two C++ functions have the same idea but drastically different runtime?

Tags: c++

Question from leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/

My answer:

**Algorithm 1 - using while:**

```
    int removeElement(std::vector<int>& nums, int val) {
       if (nums.empty()){ return 0; }
       int i = 0, j = 0; // two pointers
       while (j < nums.size()){
           if (nums[j] == val){
               j++; // skip the value to be removed
           } else {
               nums[i] = nums[j]; // copy the value to a previous cell
               i++;
               j++;
           }
       }
       return i;
   }
```

Someone else's answer.

**Algorithm 2 - using for:**

```cpp
        int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
           int l=nums.size();
           int k=0;
           for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
           {
               if(nums[i]!=val)
               {
                   nums[k]=nums[i];
                   k++;
               }
           }
           return k;
       }
```

The first answer **(Algorithm 1)** has `8ms` runtime while the second has **(Algorithm 2)** `4ms` runtime. From what I see the implementations are the same.

Why the difference in runtime?

---

**Inconsistent behavior**

Also, the runtime of **(Algorithm 1)** isn't consistent: the first submission has `8ms` runtime, the second and third have `4ms` runtime, and the last has `0ms` runtime. Does this behavior have something to do with Leetcode's platform? 
[image: My screenshot of 4 submissions]

Comment: The for-loop optimized while the other repeatedly calls size(); if you replace that with a constant, I think the while will perform significantly better.  There's no benefit to a call to size each time as this is known before the loop begins and won't change during iteration.

Comment: One difference I see is that the first fragment calls `size()` repeatedly, while the second only calls it once and caches the result. I find it hard to believe this alone doubles the execution time, unless you are measuring a non-optimized build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-consider what you're asking. I got ***4ms*** runtime on your ***first answer***:

[image]